# How to hide node_modules of a child project in node.js/webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

I have two Vue 3 projects - a library and a main project.

**Library**
I build this project as Vue 3 library

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name index src/index.common.ts
```

In this project I use `js-joda`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@js-joda/core": "^5.2.0",
    ...
}
```

in order to remove `node_modules` of the library from webpack bundle I do the following in the library `vue.config.js`:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
...
configureWebpack: config => {
  config.target = 'node';
  config.externalsPresets = { node: true }; 
  config.externals = [nodeExternals()]; 
},
```

**Main project**
I also use `js-joda` in this project and as my library is local I have the following in `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@js-joda/core": "^5.2.0",
    "my-lib": "file:./../../my-lib",
     ...
}
```

**Problem**
When I build `main project`, with the configuration I described above, two versions of `js-joda` library are included in JS bundles . One version is taken from `main-project/node_modules` and another from `my-lib/nodes_modules`. As a result I have different function `instances` with the same name what gives me wrong results in my code.

If I remove `my-lib/nodes_modules` before building `main project` then everything is ok. However, to do it every time before building `main project` isn't a good solution. Besides I work at two projects simultaneously.

Could anyone say, how I can hide `my-lib/nodes_modules` from `main project` in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

In your library, you should list `js-joda` under `peerDependencies` while in your main project you should list `js-joda` under `dependencies`.

For more information - https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution - it didn't work. It worked only when in the library I moved `js-joda` to `devDependencies`, but I wouldn't like to do it.

Comment: Well, if that did not work for you - you can add `transpileDependencies: ['your-library']` in your `vue.config.js` and then it will use only one instance of `js-joda`.